# Need to transpose Table Data with adding 0 for non existing column

Tags: sql, pivot-table, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have data as follows -

```
FieldValue         FiledID    UnqiueID
Name1                 13          1
Address1              14          1
NAme2                 13          2
Address2              14          2
Name3                 13          3
Address3              14          3
Date1                 15          3
Date2                 16          3
Date3                 17          3
```

I would like to transpose it.
My outcome will be as follows -

Name1       Address1    0        0     0
Name2       Address2    0        0     0
Name3       Address3    Date1 Date2 Date3

I was trying to do it through PIVOT, but no success.
Like to achieve it through SQL not preferring any SP.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to do this with conditional aggregation instead of `pivot`:

```
select max(case when FieldId = 13 then FieldValue end) as Name,
       max(case when FieldId = 14 then FieldValue end) as Address,
       max(case when FieldId = 15 then FieldValue end) as Date1,
       max(case when FieldId = 16 then FieldValue end) as Date2,
       max(case when FieldId = 17 then FieldValue end) as Date3
from table t
group by uniqueid;
```

Comment: But in this scenario, my FieldValue is not constant and it's varying. As you can see that Name1, Name2, Address1, Address2 etc

Comment: @user1841927 . . . This query should return the values that you are looking for for each unique id.